# How can I show a value on the screen without blocking the UI and make it fade out with style in android activity?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I'm making a word game for android, and basically whenever a user enters something right I'm updating the score in the application, and I want to show the score on the screen to make it show in big then fade out slowly and get smaller, how can I do that? and is it possible to implement it in an AsyncTask class?
This is the method I'm using to check if the word entered is right.

```
    public class checkWord extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

    private String c;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        int size = correctWords.size();
        String word = arg0[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(correctWords.get(i))) {
                publishProgress("bad");
            }
        }

        try {
            c = bufferedReader.readLine();
            while (c != null && !c.equalsIgnoreCase(word)) {

                c = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }

            if (c != null) {

                correctWords.add(0, word);
                score += word.length();
                publishProgress("good");

            } else {
                incorrectWords.add(0, word);
                publishProgress("bad");

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        closeWordFile();
        openWordFile();
        return null;
    }
```

So is there anyway I could pass a param to the publishProgress so that in onProgressUpdate I draw the score they got, for example +3 then make it fade out?
This is my onProgressUpdate where I add seconds to the timer and play a sound if it's a valid word or not

```
         @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        if (values[0].matches("bad"))
            failureSound.start();
        if (values[0].matches("good")) {
            successSound.start();
            if (countDownTimer != null) {
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                startTimer(countDownTime + c.length() / 2);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of Single threaded model in Android, only main thread can update UI, You can try the same in

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
{
    public void run() 
    {}
}
```

method.

Comment: ok, but how do I actually draw the score? I am still new to android and want to simply draw "+3" on top of the screen then fade it out.. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Instead use a toast message. It will not affect your UI.

Comment: I was hoping to do something a little more attractive. But your idea was great! 
I created a class extending the Toast and customized it then used it. Thank you very much

Comment: Attractiveness is secondary thing, but the functionality is important. So, try this, and if you are satisfied with your output, then go for more attractive one :-)

Comment: it is very helpful indeed, thank you!
However since I do not have a reputation of 15 yet, I cannot upvote, sorry :(
I marked it as the correct answer though